# invalid QName when transforming a .net XSLTransform

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I have a piece of XML that is structured similar to this:

```
 <root>
      <score name="Exam 1"><value>76</value></score>
      <score name="Exam 2"><value>87</value</score>
 </root>
```

and I would like to transform it to look like this:

```
<root>
     <Exam 1>76</Exam 1>
     <Exam 2>87</Exam 2>
</root>
```

Following [this article](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21846) I am using this stylesheet:

```
    <stylesheet>
        <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
            <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match='score'>
                <xsl:element name='{@name}'>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
    </stylesheet>
```

However, when I transform it and load it into a document, I receive this error:

> System.Xml.Xslt.XsltException: 'Exam 1' is an invalid QName

It seems that many of the google results show people with this error have passed an empty string somehow, the error is "" is an invalid QName, but that's not the case here.

What is the problem?  Is there a better, alternative solution?

Comment: It may be the whitespace in the nodename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a space in an element name.